# resize target div based on clientwidth of other div whose width is set to auto

Tags: html, resize, getelementbyid, dynamic-css

I'm trying to dynamically resize the width of one DIV (the target) based on the clientWidth of another (the source).

Note: The CSS Style of the source DIV is width:auto;

1st problem: It doesn't work... it must be my syntax or something..?

2nd problem: It needs to dynamically resize as user changes browser window (recall script on window resize). How ???

Javascript:

```
<script>

// START RESIZE WIDTH SCRIPT
function resizetarget(){

var resizesource = document.getElementById('section');
var sourcewidth = resizesource.style.clientWidth;
var resizetarget = document.getElementById('collpilewrapper');
var targetwidth = resizetarget.style.clientWidth;

targetwidth = sourcewidth;

}

</script>
```

CSS:

```
.section{
    width:auto;
    max-height:75%;
    top:60px;
    bottom:60px;
    margin-bottom:60px;
    left:280px;
    right:0px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#FFF;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
}
.section li{float:left; display: inline; }
.pane{
    overflow:auto;
    clear:left;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }

#collpilewrapper{
    min-width:900px;
    min-height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#69C;
    display:table-column;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<!--start content-->

<div class="section">

<div id="pane-target" class="pane">

<ul class="elements" style="width:16000px">

<!--box 0 -->
<li>
<!-- START landing group -->

    <div id="collpilewrapper">

          <div id="collpile1">
          <img src="images/coll-missy-714x737.jpg" /></div>

          <div id="collpile2">
          <img src="images/coll-girls-602x476.jpg" /></div>

          <div id="collpile3">
          <img src="images/coll-toddler-421x447.jpg" /></div>

    </div>

<!-- END landing group -->

</li>

<!--box 1 -->
<li>
<!-- START missy group -->
<div id="adbox">
<img class="largead" src="images/storypic-na.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="adbox">
<img class="largead" src="images/videostill1.jpg" />
</div>
<!-- END missy group -->

</li>
</ul>     
</div>
</div>

<!--end content-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kyH4/2/)

I used jQuery since I find it easier to work with. There's a couple of problems I noticed. You were targeting the element by ID but section is a class, not an id. `style.clientWidth` isn't officially supported from what I saw when I googled it. It looks like it's something that IE used to use (honestly I don't know anything about it).

***jQuery***

```
function resizeWidth(source, target){
    var sourcewidth = $(source).width();

    $(target).css({
        "width": sourcewidth
    });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeWidth("#section", "#collpilewrapper");
});
```

Whatever code you place inside of this will run when the window has been resized.

```
$(window).resize(function() {

});
```

`resizeWidth()` is a function that I made myself. It takes in a `source` and a `target`.

`width()` will give you the width of an element.

`css()` allows us to directly change the CSS.

Lastly, you'll notice that it doesn't look like the large blue box is re-sizing. That's because you've put a minimum width of 900px. Also, the event will only fire when you re-size the browser. It won't do anything when you first load up a page.